# How one can copy/paste a route and get the 'right' page using React-router?

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, reactjs, redux

Routing is implemented on client and looks something like:

```
<Provider store={ store }>
        <Router history={ browserHistory }>
            <Route path="/" component={ Layout }>
                <IndexRoute component={ Tracking }></IndexRoute>
                <Route path="users" component={ UserTable }></Route>
                <Route path="user/:login" component={ UserPage }></Route></Route>
            </Route>
        </Router>
</Provider>
```

Server-side router looks something like:

```
app.get('/', checkAuthStatus, redirect.index);
app.get('*', redirect.UndefinedRoutes);
```

The problem is that when one copies a route (for example /user/32) and pastes it in different browser tab or just refreshes page /user/32, the client sends request to server which in its turn interprets it as a request to '*' and redirect wherever UndefinedRoutes redirects (usually to the main page). So, the question is, how to redirect to 'right route', which is in given case /user/32 ?

Comment: Depend on what you want, isomorphic app or not ?

Comment: Did you try with `app.get('/user/:userId', yourParams);`? Also why do you need routing on the server when you use React Router? Doing any serverside rendering?

Comment: @SteevePitis I don't know actually.. Could you suggest what you think best solution?

Comment: @FabianSchultz Server router handles AJAX requests to APIs. All the routing between pages is on the client..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not doing any serverside rendering, you don't need routing on the server. You only need to configure a fallback, for example like this:

```
import fallback from 'express-history-api-fallback';
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';

// Set up express
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const root = `${__dirname}`;

// History Fallback for express
app.use(express.static(root));
app.use(fallback('index.html', { root }));

// Listen
server.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
```